# Bug in pandas resample/TimeGrouper

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a reproducible example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Timestamp, TimeGrouper

i = [Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:01.543999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:02.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:02.180000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:04.380000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:14.744000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:17.380000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:19.860000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:19.996000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:32.823999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:37.867999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:41.956000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:41.956000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:46.584000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:46.584000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:46.584000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:46.584000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:46.584000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:46.584000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:46.584000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:46.828000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:46.828000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:49.047999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:53.668000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:53.668000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:55.675999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:55.675999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:55.675999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:55.675999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:55.464000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:50:57.123999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:02.127999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:02.327999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:07.484000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:07.484000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.504000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.520000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.119999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.119999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.119999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.119999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.119999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.119999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.119999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.119999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:08.119999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:15.547999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:15.547999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:15.547999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:16.996000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:16.996000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:23.888000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:24.671999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:26.719999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:26.719999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:51:29.924000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:00.372000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:00.372000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:00.372000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:00.372000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:02.900000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:02.900000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:02.900000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:02.900000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:05.883999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:05.883999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:05.883999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:05.883999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:05.883999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:05.888000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:05.888000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:29.119999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:31.319999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:31.319999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:31.319999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:31.319999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:31.319999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:31.319999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:31.319999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:31.319999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:31.319999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:33.676000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:33.987999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:33.987999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:33.248000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:43.288000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:43.288000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:43.288000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:45.068000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:45.068000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:45.068000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:45.068000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:48.259999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:48.259999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:57.196000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:57.196000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:57.196000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:57.196000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:57.196000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:52:59.743999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:00.244000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:00.248000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:00.356000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:00.380000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:03.012000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:14.055999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:18.447999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:18.447999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:18.472000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:18.472000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:27.259999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:30.831999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:30.831999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:30.831999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:30.831999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:30.831999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:30.831999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:30.840000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:30.840000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:31.631999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:41.776000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:44.119999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:52.319999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:52.319999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:54.239999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:54.243999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:54.243999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:54.243999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:53:54.311999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:04.268000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:04.268000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:04.268000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:05.980000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:08.959999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:08.959999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:09.144000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:09.223999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:09.223999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:09.223999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:10.828000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:10.828000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:10.828000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:10.828000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:10.828000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:10.828000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:10.828000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:10.828000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:12.751999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:15.480000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:15.480000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:15.480000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:15.484000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:15.484000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:15.484000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:15.484000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:15.484000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:15.484000+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:16.963999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:16.963999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:17.460000+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:34.519999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:34.519999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:35.319999+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:35.319999+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:35.319999+0000', tz='UTC')]

p = [1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75,
 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25,
 1965.25, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.5,
 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75,  1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75,
 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.75, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.75, 1965.5, 1965.75, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.5,
 1965.5, 1965.5, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25,
 1965.5, 1965.25, 1965.5, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.5,
 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1964.75, 1964.75, 1964.75, 1964.75,
 1964.75, 1964.75, 1964.75, 1964.75, 1964.5, 1964.5, 1964.5, 1964.75, 1964.75, 1964.75,
 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.25, 1965.25,
 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.0, 1965.0, 1965.25,
 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25, 1965.25]
```

Now let's create the DataFrame:

```
df = DataFrame(data=p, index=i, columns=['price'])
```

What data looks like for the minute `03:54`:

```
df[df.index >= Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:00+00:00')].head(12)

                                    price
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1964.75
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1964.75
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1964.75
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1964.75
2015-10-07 03:54:04.268000+00:00  1964.75
2015-10-07 03:54:04.268000+00:00  1964.75
```

The first price is `1965.00`. Now let's create 1-minute bars using pandas `resample` method:

```
df.resample(rule='1Min', how='ohlc', closed='left', label='left')

                             price                           
                              open     high      low    close
2015-10-07 03:50:00+00:00  1965.25  1965.75  1965.25  1965.50
2015-10-07 03:51:00+00:00  1965.75  1965.75  1965.25  1965.50
2015-10-07 03:52:00+00:00  1965.75  1965.75  1965.25  1965.75
2015-10-07 03:53:00+00:00  1965.50  1965.75  1965.25  1965.50
2015-10-07 03:54:00+00:00  1964.75  1965.25  1964.50  1965.25
```

The open price is `1964.75` when it should be `1965.00` at `03:54`.

Adding a row column shows the issue perfectly:

```
df['row'] = range(1, df.shape[0] + 1)
grouped = df.groupby(TimeGrouper(freq='1Min', closed='left', label='left'))
grouped.get_group(Timestamp('2015-10-07 03:54:00+00:00')).head(12)
                                    price  row
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1964.75  189
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1964.75  188
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1964.75  187
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1964.75  186
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00  185
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00  181
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00  183
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00  182
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00  180
2015-10-07 03:54:02.648000+00:00  1965.00  184
2015-10-07 03:54:04.268000+00:00  1964.75  190
2015-10-07 03:54:04.268000+00:00  1964.75  191
```

The class `TimeGrouper` changes the order of the rows when the timestamp is identical.

A temporary solution is to sort each group by the row column before applying the `ohlc` transformation.

Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: What version of pandas? Why not use the OHLC method...

Comment: Pandas version 16.2

Same issue with OHLC: 
x['price'].resample('1Min', closed='left', label='left', how='ohlc')
2015-10-07 03:54:00+00:00  1964.75  1965.50  1964.50  1965.25

Comment: I don't believe all pandas sorts are necessarily stable, so I'd guess that resample is doing some non-stable sorts?  If so, I suppose that you would need to do something similar to what you did and just sort manually on some unique column.

Comment: I'm not even sure how the sort operation works here when there are several identical timestamps.

Comment: It depends on the sort method.  `kind='mergesort'` preserves existing order but other methods will not.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort.html  I couldn't tell you offhand what is happening behind the scenes, but I believe 'quicksort' is generally the default, meaning original sort order is not preserved when the sort key is not unique.

Comment: I tried the different algorithms but they all produced the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may work for you.

```
df = DataFrame(data=p, index=i, columns=['price'])
df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='index').set_index('index')

df.resample(rule='1Min', how='ohlc', closed='left', label='left')
```

it shows o/p as

```
                            price
                            open    high    low     close
index               
2015-10-07 03:50:00+00:00   1965.25 1965.75 1965.25 1965.50
2015-10-07 03:51:00+00:00   1965.75 1965.75 1965.25 1965.50
2015-10-07 03:52:00+00:00   1965.75 1965.75 1965.25 1965.75
2015-10-07 03:53:00+00:00   1965.50 1965.75 1965.25 1965.50
2015-10-07 03:54:00+00:00   1965.00 1965.25 1964.50 1965.25
```